# Route traffic in kubernetes based on IP address

Tags: kubernetes

We have need to test a pod on our production kubernetes cluster after a data migration before we expose it to our users. What we'd like to do is route traffic from our internal ip addresses to the correct pods, and all other traffic to a maintenance pod. Is there a way we can achieve this, or do we need to briefly expose an ip address on the cluster so we can access the pods directly?

Answer (score 1):

What ingress controller are you using?
Generally ingress-controllers tend to support header-based routing, rather that source ip based one.

Say, `ingress-nginx` supports header-based canary deployments out of box.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary.

Good example here.
https://medium.com/@domi.stoehr/canary-deployments-on-kubernetes-without-service-mesh-425b7e4cc862
Note, that ingress-nginx canary implementation actually requires your services to be in different namespaces.

You could try to configure your ingress-nginx with `use-forwarded-headers` and try to employ `X-Forwarded-For` header for routing.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-forwarded-headers

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I think we're using `nginx` ingress controllers, but I couldn't be certain without checking. I'll have to try some of these suggestions and see if they work for our use cases.